# Extracting Last column using VI

Tags: regex, unix, vim, awk, vi

I have a csv file which contains some 1000 fields with values, the headers are something like below:

`v1,v2,v3,v4,v5....v1000`

I want to extract the last column i.e. v1000 and its values.

I tried `%s/,[^,]*$//` , but this turns out to be exact opposite of what i expected, Is there any way to invert this expression in VI ?

I know it can be done using **awk** as `awk -F "," '{print $NF}' myfile.csv`, but i want to make it happen in VI with regular expression,Please also note that i have VI and don't have VIM and working on UNIX, so i can't do visual mode trick as well.

Many thanks in advance, Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you just want

```
%s/.*,\s*//
```

`.*,` is match everything unto the last comma and the `\s*` is there to remove whitespace if its there.

Answer (score 2):

You already accepted answer, btw you can still use `awk` or other nice UNIX tools within `VI` or `VIM`. Technique below calls manipulating the contents of a buffer through an external command `:!{cmd}`

As a demo, let's rearrange the records in CSV file with `sort` command:

```
first,last,email
john,smith,john@example.com
jane,doe,jane@example.com

:2,$!sort -t',' -k2
```

`-k2` flag will sort the records by second field.

Extract last column with `awk` as easy as:

```
:%!awk -F "," '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont forget cut!

```
:%!cut -d , -f 6
```

Where 6 is the number of the last field.

Or if you don't want to count the number of fields:

```
:%!rev | cut -d , -f 1 | rev
```